# Directly pass the mobile number to Digits

Tags: android, phone-number, twitter-digits

I want to authenticate user on registration, I have a mobile number field in registration form. When user clicks on submit (Submit button is digits buttton ) he should receive the otp and redirected to the otp page, where he will enter the otp. I just want to skip the screen where user manually enters the mobile number.

```
     DigitsAuthButton digitsButton = (DigitsAuthButton) 
     findViewById(R.id.auth_button);
 digitsButton.setCallback(new AuthCallback() {

 @Override
        public void success(DigitsSession session, String phoneNumber) {
            // TODO: associate the session userID with your user model
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
   "Authenticationsuccessful for " + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(DigitsException exception) {
            Log.d("Digits", "Sign in with Digits failure", exception);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you actually want to do?

Comment: I want to authenticate user on registration ,i have a mobile no. field in registration form when user click on submit(Submit button is digits buttton )he shud receive the otp and redirected to the otp page where he will enter the otp.I just want to skip the screen where user  manually enters the mobile no.

Comment: see my answer it gives you some hint

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using following way. I always prefer this for my App Development so this give you some hint.

> When you click the Submit button your API register your
>   mobile number and send the SMS on your mobile you just read that SMS from back-end and read the OTP and again hit your API so, from this way you can skip manual OTP screen.

Comment: any example?I new to android .

Comment: when i click on submit it redirect me to a screen where it ask me to enter mobile no.

Comment: It comes through api

Comment: Okey so you want to skip the enter mobile no screen right?

Comment: yes,It should directly go to otp screen where user will enter the otp

Comment: You have mobile number or not?

Comment: dude, i have a registration page where user is entering the mobile no. ,I just want that when user fill the registration form the mobile no he enter shud be opted on click of submit button and user shud get sms and redirected to otp page .

Comment: Okey, You confused me. Now, what i understand is In your registration page you opted the mobile number and you just need to click submit button and move to enter OTP page. Is it right?

Comment: yes,how we can achive this ,i have saved the mobile no . in string